# Strange behavior in RStudio when running code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio

**Update**: I also posted this in the RStudio IDE forum at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115008117828-Strange-behavior-when-running-code-as-chunk.  The RStudio team has reproduced the bug and filed a bug report.  I'll update again if I hear any more from the RStudio team on this issue.

I've come across a strange behavior in RStudio which I've found in version 0.99.903 and 1.0.143 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, although I haven't tested earlier versions or other operating systems.  It doesn't occur in R when run at the Linux command line.  Basically, if a custom function is run twice in the same code chunk, the second time it is run, the first call to dir() works correctly but the second one does not, but instead it only returns NAs.  It occurs in a strange combination of conditions which include the following:

1) The function calls "dir()" or "list.files()" twice

2) The directory being read contains more than about 3100 files

3) The function includes a call to "plot()"

4) The function is called twice in the same code chunk

I've included a reproducible example below. I would appreciate help determining why this is happening and how to avoid it.  Keep in mind that if you run the code and wish to re-run it, you need to delete the directory created in the first step or at least the files in it in order to reproduce the problematic behavior.  Thanks.

```
# Create a directory
dir.create(path = "~/test.2017-06-06")

# Define function.  This reads the files in the directory
# twice, each time storing the result in a different vector.
# Then it prints the length of each vector and the first 
# 3 files in them. 
Function = function() {
  fileNames1 = dir(path = "~/test.2017-06-06",  
                   full.names = T)
  fileNames2 = dir(path = "~/test.2017-06-06", 
                   full.names = T)
  cat("length(fileNames1):", length(fileNames1), ",", fileNames1[1:3], "\n")
  cat("length(fileNames2):", length(fileNames2), ",", fileNames2[1:3], "\n")
  plot(1)
}

# Write 3100 files containing NULL to the new directory
fileNames = paste0("~/test.2017-06-06/file", 1:3100, ".txt")
for(i in fileNames) write(x = NULL, file = i)

# Call the function twice (this works)
Function()
Function()

# Write 3200 files to the directory 
fileNames = paste0("~/test.2017-06-06/file", 1:3200, ".txt")
for(i in fileNames) write(x = NULL, file = i)

# Call the function twice again (this doesn't work)
Function()
Function()
```